# PostgreSQL using timestamp difference in partial index for upsert

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, upsert, sql-timestamp, partial-index

I need to get real-time data and put it into a Postgres table so compare the columns oid and rcv_time respectively with newly received ones.

**If this oid previously has been inserted and its received time is more than two hours from now should be inserted otherwise only need to be updated based on oid**

So I want to create a partial index like below which indicates timestamp difference as conditional unique constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX oid_uqidx ON my_table (oid,rcv_time) where EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - rcv_time)) / 3600 < 2;
```

and as a sample my upsert query would be :

```
INSERT INTO my_table (oid, rcv_time, name)
VALUES ('730048b','2020-04-24 02:46:00','test') 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT oid_uqidx
DO UPDATE SET (rcv_time,name) = (EXCLUDED.rcv_time,EXCLUDED.name);
```

But when I try to create index the following error occurs:

```
ERROR: functions in index predicate must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

I also tried to work around without partial index by putting the where clause in upsert query
and instead, create a unique constraint on oid.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (oid, rcv_time, name)
VALUES ('730048b','2020-04-24 02:46:00','test') 
ON CONFLICT(oid) where EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - rcv_time)) / 3600 < 2
DO UPDATE SET (rcv_time,name) = (EXCLUDED.rcv_time,EXCLUDED.name);
```

But It doesn't let me have multiple same oid and always do the update.

How can I approach the problem?

Comment: A partial index can't be used in an `on conflict()` clause to begin with.

Comment: So what should I use to meet my requirement? @a_horse_with_no_name I used this tutorial [Upsert](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/)